# Disqus não carrega em site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Possuo um site em Wordpress. O qual, não carrega os comentários em qualquer post (no caso, seria o arquivo single.php). No console, aparece a mensagem:

> The resource https://disqus.com/next/config.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
>   (index):1 The resource https://c.disquscdn.com/next/embed/lounge.bundle.44672f4cc4bed783e5e2f3cb12270277.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
>   (index):1 The resource https://c.disquscdn.com/next/embed/styles/lounge.d0448456a5f42b8df8cea2098aa3acf3.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
>   (index):1 The resource https://c.disquscdn.com/next/embed/common.bundle.037f55c32651d22255e90738c195e946.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

O que pode ser?

Já desativei todos os plugins e deixei apenas o Disqus ativo e mesmo assim, não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta setar manualmente um style="width: 100%" na div que você pega do próprio Disqus ou aumentar a width da div que envolve essa div pega do Disqus